# css files not found using express-handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm using express-handlebars to render some html pages. The browser is not finding the css files that I'm linking to.
This is what my server file looks like:

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const _ = require('lodash');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');
var static = require('node-static');

var {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose.js');

var {User} = require('./models/user');

const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
var app = express();
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketIO(server);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use('/', express.static(publicPath));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
});
```

And this is how I've formatted the urls on my main layout:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="views/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The assets folder is in the root of the views folder. How can I fix this?

Edit: This is my directory structure.

[image]

Comment: Can you share complete directory structure ? Also, what about relative path in `href` ?

Comment: I just added my directory structure to the post. I tried relative paths as well, like `href="/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"`, but this did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your static path.

```
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../views');
```

Also, change `href` in `html` file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

If following is your **static** folder, as you specified to express

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/public/')))
```

and intended css file is **bootstrap.min.css** ; present at root inside of **public** folder then inside ***.handlebar** following will be path to your css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap.min.css" />
```